# How many objects are created here - Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know how many objects will be created with the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850921/how-to-know-how-many-objects-will-be-created-with-the-following-code)

I have following lines of code in a program

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = str1;
String str3 = "abc";
```

I want to know how many objects are created when above 3 lines of code is executed.

Comment: @Bragboy - No duplicate, all string literals are different there (or new is used), here they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the three references refer to the same interned [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) object.

Answer (score 3):

2, 1 string object and the string contains 1 character array.

Comment: Good catch. An array is an object, so it's (either) 2 (or 0, if "abc" has already been interned in the running jvm, see [codaddicts answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854553/how-many-objects-are-created-here-java/3854604#3854604))

Answer (score 2):

only one object is created. The rest(str2,str3) are referred to internal string pool.

Answer (score 2):

It can create `0` or `1` object.

If there is already an interned String object with value `"abc"` no objects are created and if its not present, it gets created.

Answer (score -1):

3 objects, but they all use the same interned string (i.e. the string only exists once in the running JVM).

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself. Either there will be one object (correct) or three (incorrect). It can't be both.

Comment: 3? What do you mean with object? `str2` is clearly only a reference.

Comment: So I think that the correct answer is that only 1 object is created here. Am I correct?