# How many objects created with following code?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1="Hello";

        String s2="Hello";

        String s3=new String("Hello");

        System.out.println("First String :"+s1);
        System.out.println("Second String :"+s2);
        System.out.println("Third String :"+s3);
    }
```

Comment: How many *Objects* of *What*?. `String`?, `StringBuilder`? Both? Your print statements will also create *Objects*.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850921/how-to-know-how-many-objects-will-be-created-with-the-following-code

Comment: 2 if you don't count your print statements.

Comment: There is three objects before the print statements, including one `char[]` and each print statement creates five objects.